# Create vector that store numbers divisible by 3 and another vector that stores numbers not divisible by 3

Tags: r, loops

Create two vectors "threes" and "others" in R. "threes" will store all the numbers between 1 and 100 that are divisible by 3 while "others" will store all the numbers between 1 and 100 that are not divisible by 3. I need to use an if/else clause

Comment: Kindly check what type of questions are supported at this site, Please post your codes, analysis done of the issue and specific issue which you are stuck at. Otherwise this seems to be very low quality post.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
v1 <- 1:100
indx <- v1 %%3
threes <-v1[!indx]
others <- v1[!!indx]
```